# TwitterKit doesn't have interface to control redirection to native twitter app

Tags: ios, swift, twitterkit

Currently I use `TWTRTweetView` from `TwitterKit` to display the tweets. When I tap on the tweet, the iOS system's popup shows up "MyAppName" wants to open "Twitter", and gives 2 buttons, Cancel and Open respectively. 
Then the problem is no matter which button I press on, it will redirect to the twitter native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have downloaded their source code and looking into it. And I drew a flow diagram to illustrate the issue.

[image]

As the diagram shows, the twitter SDK will try to call the deep link on tap first, if user taps "cancel" on the apple's default pop up, then the SDK will try the second attempt by calling universal link. This will cause the issue as I described in the question, which is even user taps on "cancel", my app still redirects to twitter app.